# Weblogic slow with Eclipse breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, breakpoints

Sometimes when I use Eclipse with breakpoints set, the performance of my Weblogic is very slow.  Any ideas?

The performance is slow in general - it isn't only slow when breakpoints are hit.

I'm debugging with a Weblogic on my local machine.

When I disable all breakpoints everything instantly speeds up.

I don't always have this problem.  Not sure why it sometimes happens.

I'm using Eclipse 3.2.2 with the 1.0.11 of the [Forthnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mywl/) Eclipse WL plugin.

---

Update: This appears to be due to using method breakpoints (ie: break on method start/exit).  Not sure why this is the case but the problem comes and goes depending on whether I have method breakpoints set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be due to using method breakpoints (ie: break on method start/exit). Not sure why this is the case but the problem comes and goes depending on whether I have method breakpoints set.

Answer (score 2):

Check you heap usage...at least it use to be that debugging used lots of heap and the slow down was due to GC running.  Removing all the break-points might allow the memory to be re-claimed.

A couple of releases back (in the old Workshop, pre-Eclipse) you would have to limit a debug session to 2 - 3 hrs before needing to restarting the server.

HTH
Tom

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the method breakpoint and just set your breakpoints on the first line of the method, then the problem is solved! I don't know why, but it has been working for me consistently like that!